# Slicing timestamps by month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series with pandas datestamps as the index, how do I slice the index so that I can get all values from a specific month?

```
d = {'1993-01-01 00:00:00': 10, '1993-02-01 00:00:00': 12}
s = pandas.Series(d)
s.index = pandas.to_datetime(s.index, utc=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (s[s.index.month == 2])

1993-02-01 00:00:00+00:00    12
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If by specific month, you mean February 1993, then its just:

```
s['1993-02']

1993-02-01 00:00:00+00:00    12
dtype: int64
```

If you mean all Februarys, then you can't do much better than what jezrael provided.